# Link tag wont link html and css on node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, web

I pushed my project to git, and it was working just fine. However, now that I've cloned it onto a new computer, it's unable to link my html HTML my CSS stylesheet.

Here's the directory(?):

[image: Project Directory]

And here's the link throwing the error on the node server:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />`

I'm sort of at a loss for what could be going wrong, especially after trying to link it with the path `../public/style.css`

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I can't get your problem. if the problem is in html file path 3rd option will help you. sorry if this isn't work.

1. `<link type="stylesheet" href="style.css">` - The "style.css" file is located in the same folder as the current page.
2. `<link type="stylesheet" href="public/style.css">` - The "style.css" file is located in the public folder in the current folder.
3. `<link type="stylesheet" href="/public/style.css">` - The "style.css" file is located in the public folder at the root of the current web.
4. `<link type="stylesheet" href="../style.css">` - The "style.css" file is located in the folder one level up from the current folder

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the absolute path for testing? Let's try using this method.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
```

If your server is making public folder not a part of dockroot, then that might be the case for the error.